# Android admob interstitial ads don't show

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

Manifest Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;   


...
...
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-264***********");        

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
    ...
    ...
    ...

public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

Hello everyone 
E/dalvikvm(27771): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza

E/dalvikvm(27771): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.kf.a

LogCat show this error..
Program run but it doesn't show ads.

Comment: Aparently that error has nothing to do with the ads. Could you please edit your answer and show the beginning of your Manifest? Which permissions did you add?

Comment: Make sure you have installed Google Play Services from your SDK Manager.

Comment: I added manifest permission, you can see. Also I already updated google play service from SDK manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show an interstitial ad you need to ad an extra "activity" to your manifest, for example:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

If this don't work, try adding

```
android:multiprocess="true" //or maybe
android:process=":remote"
```

---

And just an observation: it's not always a good idea to show the ad onLoad. As Google [say here](https://www.google.com/admob/monetize.html?subid=ww-en-googdev-admob&utm_source=internal&utm_medium=et&utm_term=productssubpage&utm_content=monetize&utm_campaign=googledevproductsadmob):

> AdMob interstitials are full-page ads that appear in your app at natural breaks or transition points. A common use case is after a level is completed in a game.

Comment: Thanks alot, <activity ... is ok :)

Comment: @user2772836 I'm glad i could help :D

Comment: @user2772836, if this answer solved your problem, feel free to select this answer as correct to help others find the correct answer to their problems.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot, I select now

Comment: Thanks :D No problem. Good luck with your app

Comment: used the both code. But not working. I am getting ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

Comment: @VinilChandran You probably forgot to set the AdUnitId.

Comment: @George Rappel I had already added it.  I think basic coding is correct, because everything is proper in case of "Motorola Moto G" and showing the ad. But in case of "Samsung Galaxy Pocket Plus" I am getting this error and ad is not showing.