Android AdMob interstitial ads not shows with error onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent - "Timeout for show call succeed."
I integrate Admob interstitial to my project. For the moment test with test interstitial key "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712".
After admob initilisation ad load success.
But when I try to show this interstitial, I get error:
onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent {
"Code": 0,
"Message": "Timeout for show call succeed.",
"Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
"Cause": "null"
}

Project - single activity with navigation grap. Also use Koin.
Admob version "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.5.0"
Banner ad is showing correct.
What was try:

Account admob key was inserted to google sample app with test inter key. Result: Inter showing
New project with navgraph and single activity was created and my AdmobManager with keys was inserted to it.  Result: Inter showing
Migrate files from old project to new. Result: Inter wasn't show with "Timeout for show call succeed." error
From this I can understand that keys and account is correct. Also my AdmobManager work for clean project
By debug I can see that show called from main thread
Activity for showing alive, not paused or stoped
Inrestitial object not null, contains data
Trying to add timeout after ad loading before showing doesn't help
Addig to Koin as module doesn't help

Additional information from logs:
Data before calling inter show: activity com.example.x.MainActivity@c05dd82 interAd adUnitId ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712 interAd com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbml@8817dd0
Data after calling inter show: After show activity com.example.x.MainActivity@c05dd82 interAd adUnitId ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712 interAd com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbml@8817dd0
Activity lifecircle:
before calling inter show:
onStart
onResume
After show activity com.example.x.MainActivity@c05dd82 interAd adUnitId ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712 interAd com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbml@8817dd0
onPause
onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent {
"Code": 0,
"Message": "Timeout for show call succeed.",
"Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
"Cause": "null"
}
onResume

My code:
object AdmobManager {

    private var interAd: InterstitialAd? = null
    private var loadedAdNumber = 0
    private var failedCount = 0

    fun init(context: Context) {
        MobileAds.initialize(context){}
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
            RequestConfiguration.Builder()
                .setTestDeviceIds(listOf("xxxxxxxx")).build()
        )
    }

    fun preloadAd(context: Context, adsDelegateShow: AdsDelegateLoad) {
        InterstitialAd.load(
            context,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712",
            AdRequest.Builder().build(),
            object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                    super.onAdLoaded(interstitialAd)
                    Log.i("AdsWrapper", "onAdLoaded")
                    failedCount = 0
                    interAd = interstitialAd
                    adsDelegateShow.onAdsLoaded()
                }

                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: LoadAdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)
                    Log.i("AdsWrapper", "onAdFailedToLoad " + p0.toString())
                    adsDelegateShow.onAdsLoaded()
                    if(failedCount < 15){
                        interAd = null
                        failedCount++
                        preloadAd(context){}
                    }
                }
            })
    }
    fun showInterstitial(activity: Activity, adsDelegateShow: AdsDelegateShow) {
        Log.i("AdsWrapper", "showInterstitial")
        if (interAd == null) {
            adsDelegateShow.onAdsClosed()
            Toast.makeText(activity.applicationContext, "Load waiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }
        Log.i("AdsWrapper", "activity " + activity.toString() + " interAd adUnitId " + interAd!!.adUnitId +" interAd " + interAd)
        interAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent()
                    adsDelegateShow.onAdsOpened()
                    Log.i("AdsWrapper", "onAdShowedFullScreenContent ")
                }

                override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
                    Log.i("AdsWrapper", "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent ")
                    interAd = null
                    preloadAd(activity.applicationContext)
                    adsDelegateShow.onAdsClosed()
                }

                override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(p0: AdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(p0)
                    Log.i("AdsWrapper", "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent " + p0)
                    interAd = null
                    Toast.makeText(activity.applicationContext, p0.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    preloadAd(activity.applicationContext)
                    adsDelegateShow.onAdsClosed()
                }
            }
        interAd!!.show(activity)
        Log.i("AdsWrapper", "After show activity " + activity.toString() + " interAd adUnitId " + interAd!!.adUnitId +" interAd " + interAd)
    }
    interface AdsDelegateShow {

        fun onAdsClosed()

        fun onAdsOpened() {}
    }
    interface AdsDelegateLoad{
        fun onAdsLoaded() {}
    }
}

Application:
class App : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: App
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this

        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@App)

            modules(
                listOf(
                    viewModelModule
                )
            )
        }

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
        )
        
        AdmobManager.init(this)
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("open_app", bundleOf())
        val remoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig = Firebase.remoteConfig
        val configSettings = remoteConfigSettings {
            minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds = 0
        }
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)
        remoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults)
    }

}

My Activity:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}

My activity layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_screen"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

My Fragment
class SplashFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentSplashBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var progressStatus = 0
    private var answerAdsLoadGet = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentSplashBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        AdmobManager.preloadAd(requireActivity(),
            object : AdmobManager.AdsDelegateLoad {
                override fun onAdsLoaded() {
                    Log.d("AdsWrapper", "answer got")
                    answerAdsLoadGet = true
                }

            })

        binding.progressBar.progress = 0
        binding.progressBar.progressDrawable.mutate()

        requestNotificationPermission()
        getInstalledApps()

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            while (progressStatus < PROGRESS_BAR_MAX) {
                if(answerAdsLoadGet && progressStatus < 99){
                    progressStatus += 2
                } else {
                    progressStatus += 1
                }
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    binding.progressBar.progress = progressStatus
                    val loadingPercent = getString(R.string.storage_percent_info, progressStatus)
                    binding.progressText.text = loadingPercent
                }
                delay(SPLASH_TIME_OUT)
            }

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                AdmobManager.showInterstitial(requireActivity(), object : AdmobManager.AdsDelegateShow {
                    override fun onAdsClosed() {
                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_mainFragment)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

//some other code
   companion object {
        const val SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 60L
        const val PROGRESS_BAR_MAX = 100
        const val REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION = 1001
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}

My Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.My_theme"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:process=":lottieProcess"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-APPLICATION_ID"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.flag.OPTIMIZE_AD_LOADING"
            android:value="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>


Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059908/android-admob-interstitial-ads-dont-show
fix this issue.
